# Pressing back button shows same activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-xml

I have two Activities.

1. LoginActivity
2. HomeScreen

I also have a splash screen with this setting:

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The Splash Screen then transfers the user to the HomeScreen by using this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
```

Inside the HomeScreen Activity, I check if the user is already signed in or not. If he's not signed in, I transfer him to the LoginActivity:

```
 mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this,LoginActivity.class);
                    Toast.makeText(HomeScreen.this,"H>L on no login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //toast to show me why my app is in infinite loop
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };
```

On the LoginActivity, I have a simple Login button which uses FireBase Google Authentication. Also, I check if the user is already signed in or not, and if he is, he's transferred to HomeScreen Activity:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeScreen.class);
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"L>H already signed in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };
```

And, also:

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeScreen.class);
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"L>H on login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Now, the problem is: **When I open the app, I get a splash screen and I'm transferred to the Login page. Then when I press back, I get the Login page AGAIN instead of exiting the app. Also, once I'm singed in: I get the splash screen and I'm taken to the HomeScreen. Then if I press back, I am taken to the HomeScreen AGAIN instead of exiting the app.**

Please help me out. I searched StackOverflow, but didn't quite reach anywhere. Any help is appreciated. Ask me for updates if you need more info! :)

Comment: Make sure you `finish()` your splashscreen activity when opening the login activity. As you want to remove it from the back stack.

Comment: finish the activities                  like below line                                                                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);   
 finish();

Comment: Should I do it after startActivity() or before? I'm sorry I am new to Android.

Comment: after startActivity() try once

Comment: just after startactivity you should call this.finish();

Comment: I added finish() after all the places I'm calling the startActivity(intent);
It partially solved the issue. Now, once I'm taken to the Home Screen, if I press back, I'm stuck inside the loop. But if I close the app, and reopen it, my HomeScreen closes properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, So I found a solution. Apart from the precious replies below, it was also necessary to add a flag to the intent saying FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

This is the working code:

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeScreen.class);
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"L>H on login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: adding that flag was the trick for my problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is correct, please try,

Instead of calling `startActivity(new Intent(HomeScreen.this,LoginActivity.class))`  from `onAuthStateChanged()`, simply call finish(). Hope it may help you.

Comment: I added finish() after all the places I'm calling the startActivity(intent); It partially solved the issue. Now, once I'm taken to the Home Screen, if I press back, I'm stuck inside the loop. But if I close the app, and reopen it, my HomeScreen closes properly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do like this.

```
       img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where is img? I'm not using any images, buddy.

Comment: Actually I am using imageview for back button. My imageview have back arrow. if you using any button then simply put this line before setonClickListner. Button img= (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonid);

Comment: It would be better if you suggested how MY code could be modified. I don't have any reason to use an image for a back button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement onBackPressed() and by default your app should exit. However, to exit your app you can use

getActivity.finish();

or

finishAndRemoveTask(); - it finishes all activities and removes it from recent tasks list