# Why is MainActivity reopening when the back button is clicked?

Tags: android, data-binding, navigation-drawer

When I click on the back button, my MainActivity reopens. Why is this happening?
I integrated navigation-drawer in my MainActivity, and after this, when I click on the back button, the MainActivity is recreated. If I click again on the back button, the application gets closed.

This is my MainActivity code:

```
public class BuildingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BuildingsNavigator,
    BuildingItemNavigator, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private ActivityBuildingsBinding binding;
private BuildingsViewModel viewModel;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_buildings);

    viewModel = new BuildingsViewModel(this);
    viewModel.loadBuildings();
    viewModel.dataLoading.set(true);

    if (!AppUtils.isOnline()) {
        startForResult();
    }

    binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
    binding.recycler.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2));

    binding.recycler.setAdapter(new BuildingAdapter(new ArrayList<Building>(0), this, this));

    drawerLayout = binding.drawer;
    toolbar = binding.actionToolbar;
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = binding.buildingNavigation;
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.building_nav_item:
            break;
        case R.id.delivery_nav_item:
            Intent deliveryIntent = new Intent(this, new DeliveryActivity().getClass());
            startActivity(deliveryIntent);
            item.setChecked(false);
            break;
    }
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by reopen activity??? When you press back button, it opens the activity again or create another instance of activity???

Comment: Code seems Okay. Check is there two instances of `Activity` open at a time by any chance  ?

Comment: If I click back this activity opens again

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to manifest: android:noHistory="true"

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"

        android:screenOrientation = "portrait"
        android:noHistory="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

or you can write handler for this button

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    //add what you need, for example if you want to start another activity:
    Intent intent = new Intent(AnotherActivity.this, MainActivity.class); 
    //or if you want to close:
    this.finish();
    //or
    finish();
}
```

or if you about button on ActionBar you can write it in menu

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item:
            //something
            return true;

        case android.R.id.home:
            //what you need
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I add some another code about onBackPressed and menu

Comment: Not only ActionBar, Why recalled onCreate() method when I pressed back button ?

Comment: May be in your code already exist methods onOptionsItemSelected or onBackPressed and in these methods had already written some actions like repeate onCreate or launching MainActivity

Comment: I changed my onBackPressed() and onOptionsItemSelected() methods, but not working.

Comment: I think you can see onBackPressed() method in MainActivitys' code, there doesn't other actions

Comment: Did you try delete super.onBackPressed(); in onBackPressed method and wrote instead of this something else?

Comment: Thanks to all, for spending own time. I also found answer. If who needs answer visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368918/pressing-back-button-shows-same-activity

Answer (score 0):

the Previous Activity you are coming from Has a code that it sending it back to the current activity you are in, in its  **onstart()** method. try finishing the previous activity before entering the current one

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (mFirebaseUser != null) {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mIntent);
    }
    super.onStart();
}
```

Try finishing the Activity after the Authentication

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
   FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (mFirebaseUser != null) {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mIntent);
        finish();
    }
    super.onStart();
}
```